# what is the best way to create database index on json cloumn in postgress

Tags: postgresql, database-design, index-tuning

I want to create a database index on json column on field customer_number which has the follwoing data..

```
{
    "version": "3.0",
    "order_header": {
        "platform": "CORE",
        "customer": {
            "contact_id": null,
            "customer_number": "12345",
            "customer_type": "PRIVATE"
}
}}
```

can you recommend a way to do this?
I tried this but this throws me an error

```
CREATE INDEX idxcustomernumber ON sales_order USING GIN 
((original_order -> 'order_header' -> 'customer' -> 'customer_number'));
```

The error is

```
SQL Error [42704]: ERROR: data type JSON has no default operator class for access method "gin"
  Hint: You must specify an operator class for the index or define a default operator class for the data type.
```

Comment: Why do you think a GIN index is appropriate in this case?

Comment: Or, to be more precise: what query do you want to speed up?